# Handle event content UIWebview change

Tags: ios

I used UIWebview to compose content of email 
UIWebview contains content:

```
<html>    
        <body>
            <div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica; margin-top:15px;">
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I need handle event content UIWebview change to resize frame UIWebview?

Comment: I've just made a suggestion, but I'm not entirely sure if it works. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using KVO:

```
// Put this where you create your UIWebView
[self.webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"scrollView.contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@selector(observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:)];

// Put this somewhere in the same file
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"scrollView.contentSize"] ) {
        // Ensure the web view can fit its content
        self.webView.frame = (CGRect) {
            self.webView.frame.origin,
            self.webView.scrollView.contentSize
        };
    }
}
```